# WF, WPF and Silverlight common event handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a controller that needs to capture some events(MouseMove, MouseDown, KeyDown, ...) raised by a control(this control could be WinForms, WPF or Silverlight). 
Is there a way to implement such a general controller?

**added by ChrisBD **

Background:
I have a MVC application and I have a controller(GeneralController) that has acces to IGeneralControl. This IGeneralControl will be implemented by a WPF, WF and Silverlight specific control(WFControl, WPFControl, SilverlightControl). What I want to achieve is to be able to add my code to the delegates of the control at the level of the GeneralController, without the need to implemet WFController, WPFController and SilverlightController

Comment: Are you looking at capturing these events generated from within an application in which your controller resides or are you looking at capturing these events wherever they are generated e.g. desktop, other programs?

Comment: I have a MVC application and I have a controller(GeneralController) that has acces to IGeneralControl. This IGeneralControl will be implemented by a WPF, WF and Silverlight specific control(WFControl, WPFControl, SilverlightControl). What I want to achieve is to be able to add my code to the delegates of the control at the level of the GeneralController, without the need to implemet WFController, WPFController and SilverlightController.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no forms expert but I'm skepical that you can do this with some works for all GeneralController. WPF/Silverlight use a very different event model, using staticly declared routed events.

I think you'd need to implement your WFController and a separate WPF/Silverlight controller.

Comment: I also think so ... but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I agree with GazTheDestroyer
I have had a similar problem with an application consisting of either WF or WPF controls and haven't found a way to let the controllers support both WF and WPF events and I don't think this is possible.

Because even if you could use the same events somehow all the event arguments would be from completely different namespaces.
e.g. mouseEvent: System.Drawing.Point vs. System.Windows.Point

In the end I implemented two different controllers.

Comment: It could be possible to achieve this using wrappers for event handlers and for event arguments ... but this is to much headache.